# Подскажите, как после запуска приложения java запустить исполнения метода?

Tags: java, javafx

Чтобы метод запустился автоматом, после того, как программа запустилась, пока что запускается только тогда, когда нажимаешь по кнопке старт. А как сделать чтобы сам запускался без участия пользователя? интерфейс написан на JavaFX

Нужно чтобы этот метод запустился сам, после полной загрузки программы:

```
 @FXML
public void handleStart () throws IOException {
    try {
        Thread start = new Thread();
        start.sleep(15000);
        startUpdateWeather = true;
        final int[] timeUpdate = {0};
        Thread run = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (startUpdateWeather) {
                    try {
                        timeUpdate[0] = mainApp.updateWeather();
                        System.out.println(timeUpdate[0]);
                        int time = timeUpdate[0] * (60 * 1000);
                        Thread.sleep(time); //1000 - 1 сек
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        if(startUpdateWeather) {
            mainApp.getBotOverviewController().setTerminalWeather("!START: Обновление погоды запущено!\n");
            run.start();

        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
    }
```

Пробывал запускать данный метод спомощью этого метода:

```
 @FXML
private void initialize() throws IOException {
    handleStart();
}
```

Но кроме как ошибки Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
ничего не запустилось

Comment: В методе `start()` вызвать этот метод. Не понимаю, в чём проблема.

Comment: Это решило проблему))